# Counting the number of times a value has changed within a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm evaluating a column of cells, for example `A:A`, and every time a value within a cell changes (not including the initial value), I want to be able to log the change to the appropriate cell of another column, say `B:B`.

The following is a pair of before and after screenshots demonstrating what is required:

[image] [image]

`A2`has been updated once, so `B2` should show a count of `1` and `A6` has been updated twice, so `B6` should show `2`.

A similar solution can be found [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/67250-counting-number-times-cell-value-changes.html), however this only applies to **one** cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then [A2].Value = 1
End Sub
```

Cell values aren't connected to different sheets and can be hard coded.

Comment: Please attempt to make the necessary changes to the code you found.  Stack overflow is not a code for me site.  If you have attempts that did not work please put the attempted code in the original post and explain where it fails.  Otherwise this question is too broad.

Comment: @ScottCraner I've already explained that the code is for a single cell and I'm trying to expand that into two rows, one for values and the other to record changes of the values.

Comment: You are going to want to add the vba tag, so the right people see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the solutions in your link are both particularly good *and* comprehensive enough to modify, in my opinion, so I will be posting a better one.

Also your requirements are also not *quite* specific enough, so I've made up a few extra ones.

**Assumptions:**

- All the `A:A` cell values start off empty. (Can be trivially modified to allow non-empty initial values.)
- An edit of a cell that results in the same value is still considered a "change". This would normally also include where the cell was initially empty, but my code specifically excludes this edge case.
- The "initial" value is the value *after* the first "change" to the cell. (Can be trivially modified to allow the initial value to be "empty", if that is the actual requirement.)

This is the relatively simple code:

```
'============================================================================================
' Module     : <The appropriate sheet module>
' Version    : 1.0
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : N/A
' Source     : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47405528/1961728
'============================================================================================
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change _
            ( _
                       ByVal Target As Range _
            )

  Const s_CheckColumn As String = "A:A"
  Const s_CountColumn As String = "B:B"

  If Intersect(Target, Range(s_CheckColumn)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  Dim rngCell As Range
  For Each rngCell In Intersect(Target, Range(s_CheckColumn))
    With Range(s_CountColumn).Cells(rngCell.Row)
      .Value2 = IIf(.Value2 <> vbNullString, .Value2 + 1, IIf(rngCell.Value2 <> vbNullString, 0, vbNullString))
    End With
  Next rngCell

End Sub
```

This solution correctly allows for multiple cells to be edited simultaneous, as happens when you do a multi-cell delete/paste or a fill.

**Notes:**

- The initial "change" results in a count of `0`. If you wish to hide these zeroes, set a custom number format of `#;;` for the count column.
- The code can be modified to stop a "same value" edit from counting as a "change". One of the simplest ways of doing this is to use an extra column to store the old values.

**Caveats:**

- Undo will no longer work correctly. This *can* be rectified, but it is not trivial to do so.
- Pressing an `ESC` after starting an edit is required to cancel the edit and not trigger an update.

Comment: Wow this worked beautifully, thank you very much & the assumptions were on point too. However if I try to grab the value from another sheet the counter doesn't update :(

Comment: @Anna Do you mean if you have a formula in column `A:A` that grabs a value from another sheet and the value in the other sheet is changed?

Comment: Yes! So column A:A grabs data from column A:A of sheet 2

Comment: @Anna If all the cells of column `A:A` of Sheet 1 containing values are formulae and no cells are allowed to have values directly entered, then simply place the `Worksheet_Change` sub in the Sheet 2 object code module and target the Sheet 1 `B:B` column by changing the `With` statement to something like `With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(s_CountColumn).Cells(rngCell.Row)`. If you want both formulae and directly changeable values, it gets a little more complicated. You need to use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event handler as well, and also save the previous values in an extra column.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question, say I try and grab data from sheet 2 but don't want every element, the results don't line up. For example if have a table containing alphabets with numbers, say I was results from A and G, the counter will display results In the original format displayed in sheet 2 which can become inconsistent as it'll illustrate the wrong results after "A".

Comment: @Anna I don't really understand the specific scenario you're describing, but I get the problem. If `Sheet1!A2` gets its value from `Sheet2!A3` then when `A3` changes, `Sheet1!B3` is incremented instead of `Sheet1!B2`. I've worked out a rough solution, but it is too extensive to post in a comment. This is a situation where you should ask a new followup question. Make sure you link to your first question, post your currently working code and state the issue clearly. Have a look at my edits to your questions to see what a good question should look like. Then drop a comment on this answer…

Comment: …to let me know, so I can take a look at it. Please also include precisely whether (and where) the values in `Sheet2!A:A` are used in any other formulas other than those in `Sheet1!A:A`. I also need to know if any formulas in `Sheet1!A:A` reference more than one cell in `Sheet2!A:A`. I need this info as a more general solution may be required than the one that I've come up with.

Comment: Hi, So i'm using index match in Sheet1 to match the values in Sheet 2. In some instances, I won't be needing some values so I will skip them. However when trying this formula the counter (number of times a value has changed) will still align with the table in Sheet 2. For Example: SHEET2 has values 2, 6, 22, 10. However in sheet 1 I only want to call 2, 22, and 10 (in that order), If i change the value of '6' the counter value will align with '22', which is incorrect. The aim here is to align the value with it's corresponding counter.

Comment: I'm new to this, not sure if there is a PM option where I can send you screenshot examples @robinCTS

Comment: @Anna OK got your scenario now. The problem is as I suspected, and requires asking a new question. PS There is no PM option on this site. There *are* chat rooms, however, and one *could* be created and used to send screenshot examples, but it would be a bit of overkill to do so just for that. Besides, you need 20+ rep to use them anyway. For now you can just use any image sharing site (I suggest imgur.com) to upload your screenshots, and then paste the share link in a comment.

Comment: @Anna Since you seem to have started using the site again, I suggest you take the [Tour] and (re-)read the [ask] page. Another help page that might be useful is [What topics can I ask about here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Anna I think I should have been clearer in my previous comment. Since there's no PM option on this site, I was suggesting that you post a comment on this answer to let me know when you had posted your new question. As is turns out I happened  to check up on you anyway and found out you'd posted it. PS Now that you've earned 15+ rep, you can also upvote any and every question/answer that you find useful (including accepted answers), by clicking on the up triangle at the top left of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your worksheet code after you've entered the initial values, or add code to check if this is the initial value or not.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("B" & Target.Row) = Range("B" & Target.Row) + 1
    End If
End Sub
```